# How to get same result for this sql query Without using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a query which is as follows :

```
SELECT CO.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CI.POPULATION))
FROM CITY CI INNER JOIN COUNTRY CO
ON CI.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE
GROUP BY CO.CONTINENT;
```

Now, I would want to get the same result but without using Group by as I am looking for an alternative for learning purpose. I am sure this can be achieved using subquery but I am unable to.

I have tried following ways:

```
SELECT CO.CONTINENT, 
( SELECT FLOOR(AVG(CI2.POPULATION)) FROM CITY CI2 WHERE CI2.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE )
FROM CITY CI INNER JOIN COUNTRY CO
ON CI.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE;
```

or

```
SELECT CO.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CI.POPULATION)) OVER(PARTITION BY CI.COUNTRYCODE)
FROM CITY CI INNER JOIN COUNTRY CO
ON CI.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE;
```

Comment: `SELECT FLOOR(AVG(CI2.POPULATION)) ... ` - the usage of a [`GROUP BY` aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) (`AVG()` in this case) automatically turns the query into a `GROUP BY` query. If the query does not contain a `GROUP BY` clause then an implicit group is created using all the records filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @axiac True, but what is your point?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The question reads: *"I would want to get the same result but without using Group by"*. There is no way to compute an aggregate value without using (an explicit or implicit) `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query in your answer uses `WHERE` to extract the records for each group and an implicit `GROUP BY` to compute `AVG(CI.POPULATION)` for each group. The `GROUP BY` is still there, even if it is not explicitly listed in the query; the database engine uses it internally.

Comment: @axiac Then I think the question is about writing the query without an _explicit_ `GROUP BY`.  My answer should do that, yet it fails Hacker's Rank.

Comment: I don't understand the idea behind these "without using" questions. Why do you not want to use something which is a better option  in real time? Or does the interviewer ask you such questions?

Comment: Indeed, it seems the question is about writing the query without using `GROUP BY`. The entire point of my comments above is to stress out the fact that an implicit `GROUP BY` is still used (cannot get the expected results without it) and even if it is not visible, its absence does not produce faster queries.

Comment: The MySQL documentation clearly says: *"If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows"* -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html And this is not only an implementation detail; this is how the SQL standard defines the usage of the grouping functions without an explicit `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: It's just that I wanted to learn the "sub-query way" to achieve something which can be achieved by Group by. That's why I posted such question. If anyone has a better example, Please please provide one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.CONTINENT,
    (SELECT FLOOR(AVG(c2.POPULATION)) FROM COUNTRY c1 INNER JOIN CITY c2
     ON c1.CODE = c2.COUNTRYCODE WHERE c1.CONTINENT = t.CONTINENT) AS pop_avg
FROM COUNTRY t
```

By the way, `DISTINCT` sometimes is implemented under the hood using `GROUP BY`, but I don't know how to report each continent only once without doing this.

Comment: Tim, Thanks a ton for prompt answer - however, it says "incorrect result"
I am referring to this question : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/average-population-of-each-continent/problem

Comment: @Vishal_Kotecha Try my updated answer.  By the way, in real life you would never write a query this way.  Bad question from Hacker Rank IMHO.

Comment: "By the way, DISTINCT sometimes is implemented under the hood using GROUP BY, but I don't know how to report each continent only once without doing this." you could use MySQL's user variables on T.CONTINENT to simulate grouped row_numbers and filter out where row_number != 1

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yuck.  If that's the answer Hacker Rank wants, then I would rather not answer :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually Hacker Rank does not require me to write query without using "Group by", it's just me, who wants to learn the "sub-query way" to achieve such thing which can be achieved by Group by.

Comment: Aha!  Hacker Rank doesn't want this solution, that's why I failed.

Comment: If you could provide any good example to show that expected result can be achieved with both, With Groupby and With Subquery, please please post here.

Comment: No.  This is where I stop.  It is _your_ job to have the data.  Setting up a schema could take me 20+ minutes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no problem i will do myself then, appreciate your efforts, though, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend this approach, but you can just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CO.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CI.POPULATION))
FROM CITY CI INNER JOIN
     COUNTRY CO
     ON CI.COUNTRYCODE = CO.CODE;
```

Comment: no, it will give - not a single-group group function error

Comment: @Vishal_Kotecha Perhaps Gordon was assuming that you are using MySQL, not Oracle, where this query would work.